# How to specify relative paths in grunt for less plugin

Tags: gruntjs, less

I apologize for being a complete grunt newbie.  I have node.js installed, i have grunt installed, and I am able to run "grunt less" on a gruntfile.js with a less target.  It "runs", but it doesn't do anything.

My .less files live in a source respository: C:\Workspace\dev, in directories like:
C:\Workspace\dev\Webs\RP\Content\p1\less\p1.less
C:\Workspace\dev\Webs\RP\Content\p2\less\p2.less

My gruntfile.js file lives in C:\Tools\Grunt (at least as I am learning), so I need to run the "grunt less" command from C:\Tools\Grunt.

Some questions:
1. How can I run grunt from "anywhere" rather than where the gruntfile.js lives?  I'm trying to integrate compiling less files as part of the build.

2. How do I specify the "home directory" for the .less files so I don't have to specify full paths to source and dest?  In my case, home directory would be C:\Workspace\dev\Webs\RP\Content, and my less files: would be something like:
   "rp1/less/rp1.css": "rp1/less/rp1.less" (there are several that need to be compiled).

Thanks in advance.

```
module.exports = function(grunt){

    require("matchdep").filterDev("grunt-*").forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);
    grunt.initConfig({

        less: {
            options: {
                paths: ["/c/Workspace/dev/Webs/RP/Content"]
            },
            files: {
                "rp1/less/rp1.css": "rp1/less/rp1.less",
                "rp1/less/ie9.css": "rp1/less/ie9.less",
                "rp2/less/rp2.css": "rp2/less/rp2.less",
                "rp3/less/rp3.css": "rp3/less/rp3.less",
                "rp4/less/rp4.css": "rp4/less/rp4.less",
                "rp4/less/ie9.css": "rp4/less/ie9.less",
                "rp5/less/rp5.css": "rp5/less/rp5.less",
                "rp5/less/ie9.css": "rp5/less/ie9.less"
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['less']);

};
```

Comment: Show us your gruntfile as it stands. Likely you just need to learn the right file globbing pattern.

Comment: I added the gruntfile.js to the original question post.  Thank you!

Comment: I was hoping the options: path: element would specify the starting location, but in reading the documentation again, I don't think that's what it does?

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm running on Windows 2012 and 7.  I also simplified to see if I could get one .less file compiled to .css:module.exports = function(grunt){

 require("matchdep").filterDev("grunt-*").forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);
    grunt.initConfig({
 
  less: {
   files: {
    "C:\Workspace\dev\Webs\RP\Content\rp1\less\rp1.css": "C:\Workspace\dev\Webs\RP\Content\rp1\less\rp1.less"
   }
  }
    });
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['less']);

};  Still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You should read up on [how to use the files object in Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically). Basically, you want a wildcard pattern, rather than having to specify each file individually. I think something like this might work:

```
files: [
  {
    expand: true,
    src: ['**/*.less'],
  },
]
```

Haven't tested though. You might need a 'dest' property also (either empty or just './') if it's not smart enough to figure it out on its own.

Also consider using [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) instead of grunt if you're just starting your project, I find the way it separates out the 'src' and 'dest' config rather than combining them into a 'files' object much more natural. Also I've worked with less and [sass](http://sass-lang.com/) and have found the latter to be vastly superior (mostly because of the mixin libraries available, but it's also a more capable language in its own right), and it's pretty easy to move across from one to the other.

Comment: That kind of glob rule isn't feasible because I only want to compile the master .less file, and not it and all of the individual .less files in the repository.  In my previous comment, I'm just trying to get grunt to compile  ONE .less file into a .css file.  Grunt runs and says "Running less:files" and "Done, without errors.", but it doesn't do anything.  I've used linux paths, git-bash paths, windows paths ... grunt cheerfully says "Done without errors".  Thanks for the pointer to the doc.  I'll keep throwing spaghetti against the wall and see if anything sticks.

Comment: @Moffat Then just don't use the `*` glob and assign only the master file to the `src`. Read http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically I suppose the `src` *and* the `cwd` are what you actually need.

Comment: Yes - until I can get a single explicit path to compile, it makes no sense to try to use a glob.  And I still cannot get one .less file to compile into a .css file.